# need help to send variable from javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i try to send some data from html to process page. i want to do this use javascript. 
the javascript is:

```
     $('#search').click(function(){
             var param = serialize({
                        action:"searchmodelqp",
                        jhead:"aaData",
                        month:$("#search_month").val(),
                        year:$("#search_year").val(),
                        export:"excel"
                        });
$('#link2excel' ).replaceWith("<div id='link2excel'><a href='shows_merchan.php?" + param + "'  target='_blank'>Export result as Excel file</a></div>");
            });
```

and i send it to this:

```
if(getVar('export')=='excel'){
                $expexcel = 'excel';
                } else {
                $expexcel=0;
}
switch(getVar('action')){
           case 'searchmodelqp':                             
                   modelqp(getVar('jhead'),getVar('month'),getVar('year'),getVar('export'));
                   break;
           }

function modelqp($jsonhead,$month, $year,$export){
                $Month = mysql_real_escape_string($month);
                $Year = mysql_real_escape_string($year);
                switch($jsonhead){
                        case 'aaData':
                                //i put mysql query here
                        break;
                        }

if($export==0) {
          //do something
} else {
        //do something
}
```

how do i do to make it clear?because i have no result for this(script do nothing).

Comment: if you firebug , can you watch the net panel and see if it sucessfully completing the ajax request.do one more thing , print an alert statement inside success and check it is coming there.

Comment: i suspect something wrong here data: { action:"searchmodelqp",
                            jhead:"aaData",
                            month:$("#search_month").val(),
                            year:$("#search_year").val(),
                            export:"excel"
                            },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change at this part:

```
var param = jQuery.param({action:"searchmodelqp",jhead:"aaData",month:$("#search_month").val(),year:$("#search_year").val(),export:"excel"});
```

Answer (score 0):

change your data as below

```
data:action="searchmodelqp&jhead="aaData"&month=$("#search_month").val()&year=$("#search_year").val()&export="excel"
```

Comment: @klox ,if you are following your sytax add double quotes to action ,jhead etc  like this "action="

Comment: @klox , what happened did you check firebyg net panel for the ajax result

Comment: i try to rollback to my script then the result: open the new blank tab of browser